# ES6 and importing issue with multiple exports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm trying to get an index.js working with [create-index](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-index) but I'm having issues getting everything to work.

I have the following:

**/modules/utils.js**

```
export function func1(){ ... }

export function func2(){ ... }

export function func3(){ ... }
```

**/modules/index.js [auto created]**

```
export { default as utils } from './utils.js';
```

**/main.js**

```
import utils from './modules';
utils.func1();
```

But I can't get access to just the utils no matter what i do. I've tried a fair few ways of importing from ./models but the best i can get is `import * as modules from './modules'` but then i can't actually use anything.

Not sure if I'm doing something stupid or if my use of an index.js is wrong in this situation.

Comment: does `import { utils } from 'modules';` work? I don't know about `create-index` but import without curly brackets is a default import whereas `export` with curly braces is a named export

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your utils.js module has no default export, therefor re-exporting it from the module index won't help anything.

You can use either

```
// main.js
import * as utils from './modules/utils';
utils.func1();
```

or

```
// modules/index.js
export * from './utils.js';
```

```
// main.js
import * as modules from './modules';
modules.func1();
```

or

```
// modules/index.js
import * as utils from './utils.js';
export { utils }
// export * as utils from './utils.js' is proposed and supported by transpilers
```

```
// main.js
import { utils } from './modules';
utils.func1();
```

(you could also default-export the `utils` from index.js, but that wouldn't really make sense)

If you want to have a `utils` object with the functions exported from utils.js as methods, then I would recommend either the first or the last approach. Of course if there is only a single file in the `modules` folder it might also be sensible to drop that and just put your utils module right in the root folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After looking through closed tickets I discovered the module was not that smart and didn't check to see the exports in a given file. So would not handle multiple names exports. for now I'll run with calling the  modules directly as i was previously while i look for a smarter replacement.